# Windows fix explorer 'new' menu

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Something happened, now my explorer new menu only has shortcut and 'new folder'
Any tools to fix the menu, theres nothing in tweakui ?

Comment: See if this helps: [How to Restore Missing New Menuitem in Desktop and Explorer Context Menu?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-new-menuitem-in-desktop-and-explorer-context-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

It is caused due to corruption of the shellNew registry key. [Registry Easy](http://www.jj54.com/scan.php?tid=regy&vendor=) can fix it.
Install it & go to System Fix > Easy Repair Wiz

Comment: Yes I know - the trick is fixing it! There is somthing deeply broken with explorer, it crashes and restarts if I view any directory with an AVI file for example.

Comment: Seem like your registry is corrupt in many places. You could fix the AVI directory issue by either reinstalling/upgrading Windows Media Player or install Haali Media Splitter (http://haali.su/mkv/). Also try Registry Easy Repair Wizard with Windows Explorer & Windows Media Player ticked.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this behavior if I am in a folder that has I have insufficient privileges to directly write to. If I am in a user folder I get all the items back.

For example if I am in a folder inside `Program Files` or such. The New Folder item also shows the shield icon (probably only if UAC/LUA is enabled).

On the other hand, when I am in the `Documents` folder everything is fine.

So you may need to adjust the privileges to the corresponding folder in order to get all the items (properties, tab `Security`). I guess this is due to the fact that the `ShellNew`stuff can be handled outside the control of LUA and an app may fail to create the new file.

Answer (score 0):

If system restore is enabled, use it to restore the PC to a date before the registry was corrupted.